# Swift: How to change NSImage image source?

Tags: xcode, swift, nsview, nsimage, nsimageview

I'm a newbee with XCode and Swift. Trying to simply set an image in my view in an OS X application. The image should be loaded from the web, but I think that doesn't matter.

I created a new Cocoa App, have a list view which works. In the XIB for the list row I have placed an "Image View" element and with this I can display a static image in each row.

Now I want to change the image URL when the row loads. I dragged the line from the image to my controller class, which added the `@IBOutlet` to the code.

This is my code of the controller class:

```
import Cocoa

class ListRowViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var rowImage: NSImageView!

    override var nibName: String? {
        return "ListRowViewController"
    }

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://example.com/some-image.png")

        var image = NSImage(byReferencingURL: url!)

        self.rowImage.image(image)
    }

}
```

Now the very <strike>funny</strike> frustrating error message from the last statement (`self.rowImage.image(image)`) is

> Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSImage' to type 'NSImage?'.

OK. What does that mean and how do I fix it? Is that somehow related to optionals? I experimented with `?`'s and `!`'s but just can't figure out what XCode expects from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image` of `NSImageView` is a **property**, you can just assign to it.

```
self.rowImage.image = image
```

And, your URL is wrong `NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)` is for local files. Use `NSURL(string:)` instead.

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/some-image.png")
```

Comment: Thanks @rintaro, that was really it. I'm a bit embarrassed. In the Objective-C tutorial I was going through, there was a method `.setImage`, which now seems to be gone. Makes sense that `.image` then is a property. Guess it is asked too much from XCode to give a hint like "No such method: image". :) And you're right again with the NSURL. With both changes in place, it works perfectly. Thanks again!